# Document preview is out of date

Tags: google-drive-api

When I upload a file to Google Drive (either on the site or using the SDK), then view the preview of the file (again, either on Google Drive itself or using the preview URL returned by the SDK), then edit the file using Google Docs, then view the preview again, the changes made during the edit process are not visible in the preview. Interestingly, the thumbnail image gets automatically regenerated after a short time, so the thumbnail shows the correct content, while the preview does not.

The only way to have the preview show the updated document is to log out of Google and then sign back in.

Is this the intended behaviour? Or is there a way to update the preview with the SDK? Or force a new preview with an extra query param maybe?

Comment: This question isn't about programming related to Google Apps, so it is off-topic for Stack Overflow. It belongs on [WebApps](//webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Agreed. I posted it here because the support folks at the Google Drive forum asked me to.